# Update database of a deployed web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework and I had to add some migrations. Now I'd like to update a customer's app and database.

I considered using `update-database -script -SourceMigration migrationName` command which doesn't work because I create a view in one of my migrations and it gives me the following exception in VS Console.

> There is already an object named 'viewName' in the database.

It seems `migrate.exe` can be used too, but I'm not much familiar with its function and I prefer not to install anything on the customer's computer (because of limited access).

What's the best way to apply those migrations? I prefer to do it with a SQL script, but I can't get ride of that exception.

The migration code of the view:

```
public override void Up()
{
    string script = @"CREATE VIEW [dbo].[viewName]
                      AS
                         SELECT *
                         FROM dbo.existingTable
                         WHERE (subquery)";

    using (var db = new EFDbContext())
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script);
    }
}

public override void Down()
{
    var script = @"DROP VIEW [dbo].[viewName]";

    using (var db = new EFDbContext())
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide migration code for your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to add your views is using `Sql` inside `Up` and `Down` which ‘Up’ applies the changes to the target database and ‘Down’ reverts them:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql("EXEC ('CREATE View [dbo].[viewName] AS --etc"
}

public override void Down()
{

    Sql(@"IF  EXISTS (SELECT
                        *
                    FROM sys.views
                    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.viewName'))
                    DROP VIEW dbo.viewName)")
}
```

Comment: Wonderfully, it did the job! I just don't get it. What's the difference?

Comment: the important part is the if statement inside the SQL query, by the way, this approach is common.

Comment: I didn't add that `if`, or `exec` part! I'm using my old scripts with `Sql` function, so it should be some kind of bug.